# Unable to start program, Access is denied C# net6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2022

I have this issue where some of the projects I created for.Net6 throws the error shown in the image attached

[image]

In this instance the project was running fine, suddenly, the error started to pop up. I have tried to find a solution by myself and on the internet.

I have used different IDEs VS 2022, ReSharper, VS Code, and the error persists.

This started when I installed VS 2022 and .Net6 SDK. Was formally using VS 2019.

Any help?

So, what I have done so far was to do a system reset. Everything was working well until a couple of hours now. I tried to use CMD as admin to run. I would like to point out that I have a couple of projects on the solution, but one keeps throwing this error.

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (5): An error occurred trying to start process 'C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxxxxx\source\repos\ProjectTemplate2022v3\src\Skoruba.Duende.IdentityServer.Admin\bin\Debug\net6.0\Skoruba.Duende.IdentityServer.Admin.exe' with working directory 'C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxxxxx\source\repos\ProjectTemplate2022v3\src\Skoruba.Duende.IdentityServer.Admin'. Access is denied.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.Command.Execute(Action`1 processStarted)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.Command.Execute()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Run.RunCommand.Execute()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Run.RunCommand.Run(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, TimeSpan startupTime, ITelemetry telemetryClient)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: Has a virus checker done something to it perhaps?

Comment: I doubt that. I run Windows Defender on this system.

Comment: Did you try to run as administrator privilages?

Comment: @OnurkanBakırcı yes I have.

Comment: Do you reference any resource which is not from current project?

Comment: @Rena No, I did not. I have multiple projects throwing this type of error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem and later figured out that Windows Security (Defender) was blocking the executable.

Go to Windows Security -> Virus and Threat protection settings -> Exclusions and add your exe to the exclusion list.

Comment: This was what was causing my issue. And was unable to access the virus settings due to my company setup. So had to add the exclusions via an admin powershell. Similar to this: https://gist.github.com/Braytiner/be2497d1a06f5a9d943dc7760693d460

Comment: I excluded my entire development folder

Comment: Any idea how to do this programmatically from the project or code itself?

Comment: @Butzke the point to be noted here is that the executable itself was blocked from starting, which means no code will run even if you fix it programmatically. Second, UAC will prevent the code from making changes to system settings.

Comment: Tried soo many different things. This worked for me atlast. Thanks for sharing this answer.

Answer (score 6):

I just had the same problem. Quick fix for me to get it to run is to run using "IISExpress".. See below picture.

[image]

Comment: Yes, some time simple solutions works nice. By default the ASP.NET core template set to run the profile wit the application name, but to run locally you need as the answer state the IISExpress profile. Thanks Lawandile!

Answer (score 2):

To improve on Shameel's answer. For Windows 11:

Go to Windows Security -> Virus and Threat protection settings -> Manage settings -> Add or remove exclusions.